# Cakephp trigger bad route

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.x

I have a problem with the routing. I have an API coded with Cakephp 3.9 and when I call it it calls me another route.

I want to call the route `/api/order/customer-quotation` by POST, but the `/api/order/:id` by GET route is called...

Here is a capture of my code:

```
Router::plugin('Api', ['path' => '/api'], function ($routes) {
    $routes->registerMiddleware(
        'api-firewall',
        new \Api\Middleware\ApiFirewallMiddleware()
    );
    $routes->applyMiddleware('api-firewall');

    $routes->scope('/order', ['controller' => 'Order'], function($routes) {
        $routes
            ->connect(
                '/customer-quotation',
                ['action' => 'createOrder'],
                ['_name' => 'create_order']
            )
            ->setMethods(['POST']);

        $routes
            ->connect(
                '/:id',
                ['action' => 'getOrderDetails'],
                ['_name' => 'order_details']
            )
            ->setMethods(['GET']);
    });
```

I can not understand

Thank you

Comment: How are you issuing the request? And what exactly does it look like (Request line and headers)?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. I think my request is pretty clear, I expected my POST route is called, but it's my GET route is called. I am making a POST request so it's very strange.

Comment: That's why I'm asking you for environment information and debugging details. What user agent are you using, check what exactly your request looks like, eg what endpoint is invoked, what headers are sent, what headers do you get in the response, etc. Remember that no one here can see what you are doing, just stating that you are issuing a POST request is not enough for anyone to give you a good answer, all they could do would be guessing.